# Telerik RadTextBox position changed after upgrade from 2011

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I'm in the process of upgrading our site to Telerik, but I've noticed that in one of our controls, the RadTextBox has moved up a few pixels, and right about 100.
I can't see any reason for this, the only thing I have done is to upgrade Telerik for AJAX ASP.NET from 2011Q1 to 2014Q1 - I also noticed this a month or so ago when I attempted to upgrade to 2013Q3. Is this something to do with the skins moving into their own dll, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have labels set, even an empty space? If so, does making them meaningful or removing the property help?

You can also try toggling the EnableSingleInputRendering property to see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the labels thing, and looking for empty spaces in the item itself,
but I have now resolved this with a quick and dirty bit of css on the page to override the top and left margin for the specific id.

Comment: Basically, somewhere between these two versions of this library, Telerik have altered how this piece of work calculates borders, margins, padding etc. What it seems to do now, is completely ignore what ever it did before, and randomly add on enormous amounts of padding left or right, or occasionally take it off.